# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k*a_{2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a_k$ $\ge$ $0$, for $k$ $\ge$ $1$, and $a^{k's}$ are decreasing in $k$. Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k*a_{2^k}$ converges. I was asked to proof this but I am stuck.

The ratio test didn't help me. So I thought about the comparison test. However, using the comparison test at most I can proof the statement one way. Does someone have an idea how to prove this?

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are probably trying to solve what is knowns as **cauchy condensation test**. And the index of $a$ should be $2^k$, not $k^2$.

Comment: You mean $a_{2^k}$ rather than $a_{k^2}$. Hint: $2^ka_{2^k} \leq 2\sum_{l=2^{k-1}+1}^{2^k}{a_l}$ and $2^ka_{2^k} \geq \sum_{l=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}{a_l}$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: "I was asked to proof" ... what would be the point of asking you to prove it, if you just get the solution here?

Comment: @GEdgar, we were allowed to use books/internet since this is more difficult than the stuff we get in class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Cauchy condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test); see that link for a derivation, which you'll understand if you know the most popular proof the harmonic series diverges. But in short, $$a_1+\sum_{j=2}^n2^{j-1}a_{2^j}=a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{2^n-1}a_{2^{\lceil\log_2k\rceil}}\le a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{2^n-1}a_k\\=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}a_k\\\le\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}a_{2^{\lfloor\log_2k\rfloor}}\le\sum_{j=1}^n2^{j-1}a_{2^{j-1}}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it was  $a_{2^k}, not $a_{k^2}$. I can accept an answer in 7 minutes so I will do that soon. Thank you!